# Why does my wifi speed slow dramatically when more than one person uses it?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, signal-strength

Whenever both my roommate and I use the wifi in a certain room in our apartment, it slows dramatically for me. It doesn't slow for him. If he uses it in another room, it's fine; if I use it in another room together with him, it's fine; it's just in this particular room. Does anyone know of a reason this could be?

Comment: I'm guessing that his WiFi card is causing radio interference for your WiFi card. There may be configuration settings that can fix this. Others who know more can chime in.

Comment: Check if you have QoS enabled on your router. Perhaps change to 5GHz instead of using 2.4GHz

Comment: What kind of lights/fans or other radio sources are in the rooms? If you can use your laptops together fine in other rooms that would indicate it's something about the room itself and not necessarily the laptops (beyond the fact that your roommates wifi card might handle [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) better than yours) ..

Comment: Does he have some old equipment that only does 802.11b? b and g (and n) protocols get into each other's way, causing slowdowns.